# WPF .NET 6 - opening of the windows increases significantly in time

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a huge problem with my application made in WPF. I'm using .NET 6 and Visual Studio 2022 version 17.2.5.

The main problem I've encountered is that each time I open the same window (or any other) it extends in time. For testing purposes, I created a window object, then create a view object (that's a usercontrol with multiple basic controls and other usercontrols inside) and attached to the 'Content' property of the window and showed the window. I don't even attach any DataContext, just controls objects. I created a destructor in the view that tells me if the object has been disposed . Closing the window deletes the view object, but each subsequent opening of the window extends in time, at the same time the memory usage of the application framework increases.

I don't know what I'm doing wrong. At first I thought there was a memory leak somewhere, but it looks like everything is being cleaned up by the Garbage Collector - so why is the ram memory consumption increasing. I've tested on different views, lighter and heavier, the difference is that the lighter ones need more reopenings to significantly increase the wait for the next opening. In summary, the first opening of a window is the fastest, each subsequent opening is slower than the previous one.

Thank you in advance :)

Comment: If you need help debugging something it would be best to include the code in your question. Please read [mre]

Comment: You need to show some code reproduces this. The minimum amount of code - not a huge dump of a project. If you don't then your question is going to get closed. But i think you've got a memory leak and that could well be how you go about instantiating content. Minimal reproduction - you read that bit?

Comment: As above, additionally did you tried this on released version and compared it's ram consuption, debug and release could be two different stories.

Answer (score 1):

I apologise if I wasn't precise enough, but the problem was very general and it was hard for me to provide any specific code to analyse. The problem occurred throughout the application, in all windows, usercontrols etc. However, I found the cause that was causing the problem. I am using Syncfusion styles and it is possible to apply the styles to the whole application by writing a line of code like this in the application class (App.xaml.cs):

```
SfSkinManager.ApplyStylesOnApplication = true;
```

When I deleted this line everything quadrupled in speed and I no longer observe these application jams. Maybe someone will find this information useful. Thank you for your interest. Best regards.